# Blocking content with .htaccess prevents it to load even in the allowed domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block content from loading if it's accessed directly or from an unallowed domain. To do that I'm using a `.htaccess`. So, my logic is:

- **Accessed directly**: Empty referer.
- **Unallowed domain**: Domain of the referer different from the allowed domain.

I also have to block other types of files. `jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|zip|ppt|pptx|ai|pdf|doc|xls|xlsx|psd|mov|svg`

To give more context, the content (and the following `.htaccess`) is hosted in a different domain from where I want to be able to load the content. Let's say the content is in `x.com` and I want to be able to load the content **only** in `example.com`

So this is my `.htaccess`

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^https://www.example.com/" letitpass
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=letitpass

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
  RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|zip|ppt|pptx|ai|pdf|doc|xls|xlsx|psd|mov|svg)$ - [F,NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

This works partially as expected. The problem is that some content (like an image) inside a PHP or HTML document isn't loading even in the allowed domain.

This is the result: (screenshot from `example.com/a-page/`)

1. An image `<img src="https://x.com/image.png">`. It works as expected. It loads only in `example.com`

[image]

2. An iframe with a `.pdf` document, `<iframe src="https://x.com/file.pdf">`. It works as expected. It loads only in `example.com`

[image]

3. An iframe with a `.php` document. The document has a img (`x.com/image.png`) and a pdf file (`x.com/file.pdf`). `<iframe src="https://x.com/document.php">`. It **doesn't** work as expected. The page is loading only in the allowed domain and that's fine, but some content like the image isn't loading

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: As far as I read from your code-snippets you have a page on example.com. Within that there is an IFrame loading the PHP-rendered page from x.com (which works). The PHP-rendered page again loads images and stuff and you expect them to show. This won't work, as the IFrame is sending x.com as referrer.

Comment: Thanks @fragmentedreality, your comment was very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a logical `OR` into the `RewriteCond`'s exclusion ...in order to permit the embedding for `x.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?(example|x).com/.*$ [NC]
```